# How to change broadcast periodicity of an NTP server

Tags: debian, services, ntp

I'm configuring an NTP service on debian via `/ect/ntp.conf`. I made it as a broadcast so I set my clients as listeners.

Is there a way to change the periodicity by which the NTP server sends its broadcast messages?

Comment: Not exactly OT for your question, but I would suggest using a multicast setup instead of broadcast, it's a bit more secure, and lets systems that aren't clients on your network more easily ignore the time broadcasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says that you can adjust the periodicity with `minpoll`

[How do I configure a Broadcast Server?](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm#AEN3639)